# Change the behavior of a mod_watch state function

Tags: salt-stack

I'm using the [supervisord state](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.supervisord.html) to manage my web app instances.

When a config file changes, I want to reload the supervisor config and restart affected instances. I currently do this using the `watch` prerequisite in a `supervisord.running` state, but the default `supervisord.mod_watch` state function only restarts my instances without reloading the config.

The docs say `supervisord.mod_watch` has a `reload` option, which is `False` by default. If I could somehow set it to `True` my problem would be solved. Does anyone know how to do this?

Btw: I already tried to use the `onchanges` prerequisite and just set `reload: True` when using `supervisord.running`, but somehow that prereq never gets triggered.